# Execute python scripts from another python script opening another shell

Tags: python-3.x

I'm using python 3, I need one script to call the other and run it in a different shell, without passing arguments, I'm using mac os x, but I need it to be cross platform.

I tried with

```
    os.system('script2.py')  
    subprocess.Popen('script2.py',     shell=true)
    os.execl(sys.executable, "python3", 'script2.py')
```

But none of them accomplish what I need.

I use the second script to get inputs, while the first one handles the outputs...

EDIT

This is the code on my second script:

```
import sys
import os
import datetime

os.remove('Logs/consoleLog.txt')
try:
    os.remove('Temp/commands.txt')
except:
    ...

stopSim = False

command = ''

okFile = open('ok.txt', 'w')
okFile.write('True')
consoleLog = open('Logs/consoleLog.txt', 'w')

okFile.close()

while not stopSim:

    try:
        sysTime = datetime.datetime.now()
        stringT = str(sysTime)
        split1 = stringT.split(" ")
        split2 = split1[0].split("-")
        split3 = split1[1].split(":")

        for i in range(3):
            split2.append(split3[i])

        timeString = "{0}-{1}-{2} {3}:{4}".format(split2[2], split2[1],   split2[0], split2[3], split2[4])
    except:
        timestring = "Time"

    commandFile = open('Temp/commands.txt', 'w')

    command = input(timeString + ": ")
    command = command.lower()

    consoleLog.write(timeString + ': ' + command + "\n")
    commandFile.write(command)

    commandFile.close()
    if command == 'stop simulation' or command == 'stop sim':
        stopSim = True

consoleLog.close()
os.remove('Temp/commands.txt')
```

and this is where I call and what for the other script to be operative in script 1:

```
#Open console

while not consoleOpent:
    try:
        okFile = open('ok.txt', 'r')
        c = okFile.read()
        if c == 'True':
            consoleOpent = True
    except:
        ...
```

Sorry for the long question...
Any suggestion to improve the code is welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest solution is to make the contents of you second script a function in the first script, and execute it as a [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html) `Process`. Note that you can use e.q. `multiprocessing.Pipe` or `multiprocessing.Queue` to exchange data between the different processes. You can also share values and arrays via `multiprocessing.sharedctypes`.

Comment: @Enderlike61 Yes, that's basically what it does. I've added a link to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This will be platform-dependent. Here a solution for Mac OS X.

Create new file `run_script2` with this content:

```
/full/path/to/python /full/path/to/script2.py
```

Make it executable.: `chmod +x run_script2`

Run from Python with:

```
os.system('open -a Terminal run_script2')
```

Alternatively you can use: `subprocess.call`.

```
subprocess.call(['open -a Terminal run_script2'], shell=True)
```

On Windows you can do something similar with (untested):

```
os.system('start cmd /D /C "python script2.py && pause"')
```